# Force base_profile to run

Tags: bash, solaris

When I login to a sun box:  SunOS domain.com 5.8 Generic_117350-57 sun4u sparc SUNW,Sun-Fire-V240

I start in the sh shell: SHELL=/bin/sh

I type bash to start a bash shell, then have to type . .bash_profile to load my profile.  Is there a way it can be set to automatically load the profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.bash_profile` is only used for login shells, for non-login shells (like yours), bash uses `.bashrc`.

The easiest thing is for you to add `. .bash_profile` to your `.bashrc`.

You also have to make sure that you don't print out anything in non-interactive shells, or you can break scp/sftp.

Answer (score 2):

Put

. ~/.bash_profile

in ~/.bashrc (watch out for infinite loops!). I don't use that myself, as I have most stuff in .bashrc to begin with (except, well, env. stuff and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Running *bash* like this causes it to source */etc/bash.bashrc* and then *~/.bashrc* in lieu of *.bash_profile* (and other files). Therefore, put `. ~/.bash_profile` in *~/.bashrc*, (or in */etc/bash.bashrc* to do this for all users).

Answer (score 0):

The file `.bash_profile` is run when upon login. The file `.bashrc` is run when running bash from a non-login session.

Try adding this to your `.bashrc`:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```